# Profile migration from higher to lower release version

Tags: profile, metadata, release

According to [Salesforce Winter '18 Sandbox Preview Instructions](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/08/salesforce-winter-18-sandbox-preview-instructions.html)

Each sandbox created after Sep 8 and before Production new release (middle of Oct) will become Summer 17, while created before Sep 8 - Winter 18.

We are trying to perform profiles backup by deploying them from Winter 18 Sandbox to Summer 17 sandbox environment.
We have pulled all settings: object access, class access, layout assignments.

But in Winter 18 Salesforce has added new metadata:

```
<field>Asset.StockKeepingUnit</field>
<layout>Scorecard-Scorecard Layout</layout>
<userPermissions>..<name>ListEmailSend</name></userPermissions>
```

Given examples dont exist in Summer 17. Each validation returns one error and takes about 15 minutes to be complete.

If there any easiest way to deploy profiles to downgraded version?

Answer (score 1):

List of Profile metadata, I'm not able to deploy from Winter 18 to Summer 17:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>UseWebLink</name>
</userPermissions>

<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ListEmailSend</name>
</userPermissions>

<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>standard-ChannelProgram</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOff</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>

<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>standard-ChannelProgramLevel</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOff</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>

<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>true</editable>
    <field>Asset.StockKeepingUnit</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>

<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>true</editable>
    <field>Product2.StockKeepingUnit</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>

<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>true</editable>
    <field>SocialPersona.AuthorLabels</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>

<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>true</editable>
    <field>SocialPersona.InfluencerScore</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>

<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>true</editable>
    <field>SocialPost.HiddenById</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>

<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>true</editable>
    <field>SocialPersona.IsVerified</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>

<layoutAssignments>
    <layout>ChannelProgram-Channel Program Layout</layout>
</layoutAssignments>

<layoutAssignments>
    <layout>ChannelProgramLevel-Channel Program Level Layout</layout>
</layoutAssignments>

<layoutAssignments>
    <layout>ChannelProgramMember-Channel Program Member Layout</layout>
</layoutAssignments>

<layoutAssignments>
    <layout>ScorecardMetric-Scorecard Metric Layout</layout>
</layoutAssignments>

<layoutAssignments>
    <layout>Scorecard-Scorecard Layout</layout>
</layoutAssignments>
```

I've generated objects list using Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() in Winter 18 Sandbox. By removing ChannelProgram, ChannelProgramLevel, ChannelProgramMember, SocialPersona, SocialPost.object we can reduce list by 6 elements (field permissions and tabs). Everything else remains even if run Ant for Api version 41, 40, 39 and 35.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using the Force.com IDE or Ant Migration Toolkit (recommended), you can just set the package.xml's version to 40.0, and it will retrieve only the 40.0 settings. This will allow you to migrate the settings without having to manually remove the extra permissions. Change sets are not likely to work because of the version issues.

Comment: [Salesforce Winter ’18 Release Notes, page 527](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter18_release_notes.pdf) : Asset
Added fields ProductCode and StockKeepingUnit. While Asset.StockKeepingUnit is getting pulled from winter 18 sandbox with ant, using version 41, 40, 39 and even 35.